# hide and show multiple elements with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript, HTML, and CSS, however, I cannot make a function that hides and shows the "pwdHelpWin" and "SCRNoverlay" elements once the button is clicked. please help

jsfiddle.net/1zLnsbj2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write brackets after a function name if you want to call a function and you should write a hashtag in the href if you don't want the browser to redirect you to another page

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPwdWin()">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1zLnsbj2/8/

Comment: i can open it but cant close it D:

Comment: Open your debugger and look at the error messages. You will see that you have typos in your id's (scrnOverlay and pwdHelpBtn don't exist in your HTML). You also forgot `.style` in your hide function. Feel free to vote on my answers if they help you.